# How do I suppress an unused dummy argument warning for a single function in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, compiler-warnings

I have the following FORTRAN code:

```
FUNCTION inverse_deterministic_cdf(dist, p) RESULT(value)
    !=========== result ============
    REAL(C_DOUBLE) :: value

    !====== input parameters =======
    TYPE(deterministic), INTENT(IN) :: dist
    REAL(C_DOUBLE), INTENT(IN) :: p

    !======= subroutine body =======
    value = p ! This is only here to suppress unused dummy argument warning
    value = dist%value
END FUNCTION inverse_deterministic_cdf
```

In this case, `inverse_deterministic_cdf` is an implementation of an `inverse_cdf` interface, which is why there's the unused `p` here. As you can see, I have a method of suppressing the unused dummy argument, but it feels inelegant to me. Does anyone have any best practices for how they handle this? (I also want this to be compiler agnostic.) I know how to suppress the warnings universally, but I *want* to be warned when I have an unused dummy argument and I'm not anticipating it.

Edit to add (upon request):

The `inverse_cdf` interface is defined thusly:

```
INTERFACE inverse_cdf
    MODULE PROCEDURE inverse_distribution_cdf, inverse_normal_cdf, inverse_lognormal_cdf, inverse_deterministic_cdf
END INTERFACE
```

Comment: Please show us how do you define an inverse_cdf interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that you need to define a **generic interface**.

stuff.f90

```
MODULE stuff

  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTERFACE stuff_foo
    MODULE PROCEDURE foo1
    MODULE PROCEDURE foo2
  END INTERFACE stuff_foo

  CONTAINS

    FUNCTION foo1(a) RESULT(f)
    REAL :: a
    REAL :: f

      f = a

    END FUNCTION foo1

    FUNCTION foo2(a, b) RESULT(f)
    REAL :: a
    REAL :: b
    REAL :: f

      f = a + b

    END FUNCTION foo2

END MODULE stuff
```

main.f90

```
PROGRAM main

  USE stuff

  IMPLICIT NONE

  PRINT *, stuff_foo(1.0)
  PRINT *, stuff_foo(1.0, 2.0)

END PROGRAM main
```

Comment: I have a generic interface (`inverse_cdf`), but it is meant to be called with two arguments, hence the unused dummy argument. What I'm wanting is for the user to not have to write different code for dealing with a deterministic "random" variable than for dealing with a truly random variable (e.g., a normal distribution).

Comment: Hmmm... I failed to understand even your intentions. If you don't need a second argument in a function call - you don't need it. Hiding that fact from user is 100% misleading. Generic interfaces in Fortran aren't analogues to Java interfaces. They are just a special syntax for describing the overloaded function. Any two procedures with the same generic identifier shall differ. For example they can differ in arguments count. This is very common.

Comment: I agree with kemiisto, if you want to overload use a generic interface, if not, well, then you don't...  If I get it, you're saying you want the user to call `inverse_cdf(dist, p)` and `inverse_deterministic_cdf(dist, p)`?

Comment: @steabert: The user would never have a reason to invoke `inverse_deterministic_cdf` directly as if they know they have a deterministic variable, then the inverse_deterministic_cdf function always returns that value (as shown in this function). The function is there to allow the user to combine deterministic variables with random variables in an agnostic manner. I am definitely guilty of coming from a C++/Java background which is definitely coloring my expectations of what is elegant.

Comment: @Ben Hocking: "The user would never have a reason to invoke `inverse_deterministic_cdf`" and "The function is there to allow the user to..." seems contradictory.  Well, I guess the most important thing is if the answers helped you.

Comment: What I mean is that if the user knows it's a deterministic variable, then there's no need to perform an inverse_cdf. It's when the deterministic variable is part of an array of variables where some are deterministic and some are random that the loop can just invoke inverse_cdf without knowing whether it's dealing with a deterministic or random variable.

Comment: You can either suppress the warning or use OOP and take it to the top. I don't see the third way. The behavior you want sounds completely like polymorphism to me. There is no analogue in procedural programming. Or why do you think founding fathers invented OOP? ;-)

Comment: Yes, polymorphism is what I'm wanting, and I'm trying to trick Fortran into doing it. I guess it's just too smart for me. :P

Answer (score 0):

Since you have your procedure in a module (and thus, the procedure has an explicit interface), why not use an optional argument? E.g. something like

```
FUNCTION inverse_cdf(dist, p) RESULT(value)
    !=========== result ============
    REAL(C_DOUBLE) :: value

    !====== input parameters =======
    TYPE(deterministic), INTENT(IN) :: dist
    REAL(C_DOUBLE), INTENT(IN), OPTIONAL :: p

    !======= subroutine body =======
    IF (PRESENT(p)) THEN
        value = dist%value * p ! Some expression using p
    ELSE
        value = dist%value
    END IF
END FUNCTION inverse_cdf
```

Comment: For a deterministic "random" variable, the inverse cdf would always be `dist%value`, whether a `p` is specified or not. I.e., the pdf is a Dirac delta function located at `dist%value`. (More exactly, the probability distribution function is `δ(x - dist%value)`.)